# Azure DevOps Basic Licensing billing when having Visual Studio subscription

Tags: azure-devops, billing, user-management

If I force a basic license on a user in Azure DevOps that has a Visual Studio subscription.
Do I still have to pay 5$ for the basic license even though the user actually has a Visual Studio subscription assigned. Or does the billing system, by itself, figure out that the user has a VS subscription, even though I force a basic license for that user.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio subscribers are entitled to Visual Studio subscription features as a subscriber benefit. When you add those users, be sure to assign them the Visual Studio subscription access level.

> Or does the billing system, by itself, figure out that the user has a
> VS subscription, even though I force a basic license for that user.

The system automatically recognizes their subscription and enables any other features that are included, based on their subscription level. You don't have to pay for Users with recognized VS license: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#visual-studio-subscription-access

DevOps Basic Access Level: First 5 users free, then $6 per user per month

[image]

Visual Studio Professional subscription has DevOps Basic benefit.

Visual Studio Enterprise has DevOps Basic + Test Plan benefits.

VS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-azure-devops#eligibility

Comment: So if I set the access level for a user (who has a valid VS subscription) to Basic, will DevOps automatically set their access level back to Visual Studio Subscriber when they login? Or will their access level remain at Basic, and thus count towards the total number (and cost) of Basic users?

Comment: Yes, if a user is holding a valid VS Enterprise license, equals the Basic + Test Plan benefits in Azure DevOps. If you change this user's access level to Basic in Azure DevOps UI, upon his login, the system will automatically recognize his VS license.